# Android SO file security

Tags: android, encryption, shared-libraries

Is it possible to detect an encrypted string and an algorithm hidden in an Android **SO file?** Investigating Android security best practice right now. Thanks.

Comment: In the most general case, no; that's an undecidable task.  However, there are probably some decent heuristics one could use -- often times code is encrypted using one of a handful different techniques, and reverse engineering tools can sometimes pot them.

Answer (score 0):

Of course. It is only hidden after all. Encrypted data is much more random than than regular library code which has some sort of structure. There are tools that can detect this (some even do it for memory). The real problem is if the decryption key resides in the same binary. If it is, someone determined enough will be able to find it. Your best bet is to try to generate it at runtime by combining bits and pieces of it, but that is not bulletproof either.